# Codemirror6 and defining tags / custom schema for XML parser

Tags: javascript, xml, codemirror

I can't seem to find the codemirror6 documentation for defining a custom schema for the XML parser.

```
import { EditorState, EditorView, basicSetup } from "@codemirror/basic-setup"
import { html } from "./lang-html"
import { xml } from "./lang-xml"

let editor = new EditorView({
    state: EditorState.create({
        extensions: [basicSetup, xml()]
    }),
    parent: document.body
})
```

https://github.com/codemirror/lang-xml

Here's the reference but where do I put this and is there an example?

Comment: Have you checked here https://codemirror.net/6/examples/lang-package/ ?